# Versioning options for shared database development (schema and data)

Tags: sql, sql-server, versioning

We have multiple instances(application + database) of the application running (Dev, Test, Prod).

Our implementation process currently looks like that:

- multiple database developers work on the same database (application is developed by a separate team)
- database development process contains of adding/altering database objects and configuring application objects
- the application objects are stored in the database tables (we call them kernel tables) as data
- the database is connected to an instance of an application, there is no possibility for developers to run their own instance of the application on their local machines. (I know it is not the best approach, but currently we cannot do it differently for various reasons)

We'd like to figure out an approach and tools (preferably free or at least not very expensive)
to do the versioning on a feature level, as usually, one developer works on one feature. In the end, the feature is usually some database objects (tables, views, stored procedures) and the data inserted in the kernel (application) tables. The developer does not control the data entered by the application.

The kernel tables usually have the auto-incremented primary key, plus some dependencies like foreign keys on other kernel tables.

The ultimate goal is to have the continuous integration process in place. Meaning that we want to have an automated process which would do some tests and populate our features to other environments.

We are using both SQL Server 2014 and Azure SQL Databases.

Do you have any experiences/ideas how to handle such situation?

Thanks

Comment: I am curious to see what people use for SQL Server. Visual Studio has some built-in tools, but I never had a chance to try it with SQL Server, and it didn't work with Oracle.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will get closed as a "Recommend a tool" type post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Visual Studio Community [https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/](https://www.visualstudio.com/fr/vs/community/) with the SSDT (SQL Server Developer Tools) tools https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt

You can now create an SQL Database Project, which can handle all your database objects. In addition you can use GIT tools (github or vsts (https://www.visualstudio.com/) to store and share your code (privately).

With these tools you can manage both Azure SQL Database and SQL Server databases.

Here is a complete guide for these tools : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee70aty.aspx

Comment: Here is a SQLServerCentral article walking through an SSDT CI pipeline setup. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Continuous+Integration+(CI)/140954/

Comment: Hi, I was trying using both GitHub and Visual Studio, but the issue is that both tools are doing the versioning only on the whole database level. There is no easy way to branch only some of the database objects and create a release out of them. I tried a couple of other tools as well, like RedGate or Apes, but all of them are working more or less the same.

Comment: Another story is the data stored in the tables I mentioned.  I guess the schema comparing and integration can be managed somehow, but I really do not have the idea how to handle the data changes. In our current setup usually when I try to compare the databases data, usually the id's of the rows are not matching between environments, which is obviously understandable, as these are totally seperate environments...

Comment: I think you need to create branches to develop specific feature. Once done, you merge the branche.

Comment: Hi, I tried branching both with git and TFVC repositories. The issue is that we have only one instance of the database and the application for multiple developers. A potential solution may be branching only on some subset of the database objects, but I was not able to achieve this.

Comment: Even if multiple teams work on several parts of the database, I think you need to have a common repository (with a master branch), at least to simplify the deploiements on test and production environements. When new features are developed you should create specific dev branches, and once developments are finished you merge the dev branch into the master branch. To help, you can use the GitFlow plugin in Visual Studio.